# Use spring-batch, how to delete the data has been processed

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a table A, use MyBatisPagingItemReader to read,process,use MyBatisBatchItemWriter write the result in to Table B, then I want to delete the records which I have processed in the table A,How to do?

Answer (score 1):

I guess best way for this custom action will be add StepListener.
Something like this

```
 @Bean
   public Step stepA(ItemReader<String> readerA, ItemWriter<String> writerA) {  
          return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepA").<String, String> chunk(1)
                       .reader(readerA).writer(writerA).listener(stepListener()).build();
   }
```

You have to implements StepExecutionListener.

```
public class CustomStepListener implements StepExecutionListener {

@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    System.out.println("StepExecutionListener - beforeStep");
}

@Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    System.out.println("StepExecutionListener - afterStep. Here we will delete all records");
    return null;
}
```

}

In scope of this step you can delete records as you wish.
SqlQuery, Repository, etc.

Comment: I would recommend this approach, since the listeners are running in separate transactions. (have a look at this article: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/transactions-in-spring-batch-part-2-restart-cursor-based-reading-and-listeners/).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a CompositeItemWriter. Add your MyBatisBatchItemWriter as first writer and add a second writer, which deletes the entries from table A.

This way, everything runs in the same transaction; hence, there is no risk for data inconsistency.